# Using python, Replace the Lines in text file(.txt) with the some X string if the line contains a specific string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Python script to replace the line in text file with user choice string.

Old.txt

[image]

As per below image...

If line contains "REL", the entire line need to replace with "Released", Like wise other lines too.

```
INSP --- Submitted
No Baseline --- Draft
Rev --- Reviewed
APPR --- Approved
DRAFT --- Draft
```

Comment: 1) Welcome to Stack Overflow. 2) Post plain text instead of an image. 3) What have you tried so far? What is the problem?

Comment: Please do no post code or source data as images, copy-paste the text in the question

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to read the text file and store each line in a list as a string. First, you need to store each line of the text file in a list, as a string. You can do that using `f=open('Text_file.txt', 'r')` followed by `f_read=f.readlines()`. Now f_read is a list that contains each line of the text file at a separate index. Now run a while loop to access each line by accessing each element of f_read.

To check whether a particular line contains the desired string, write `if "REL" in f_read[i]:` where 'i' is the counter variable. Then inside this if block, write the exchange statement: `f_read[i]="Released"`. This will replace the entire line with the string "Released". Hope this solves your problem.

Have a nice day! :)